# Django Paginator is not giving output

Tags: python, django

Hope you are doing great. So there is a projects page where there are different number of projects on that page. Currently I am displaying 3 projects per page. Now I want to display number of pages that I have right now. Like there are 9 projects so there should be 3 pages.
But My paginator is not displaying any number button on the bottom of the page. Here is the code(Sorry For the bad English I tried my best to explain)

View.PY

```
def projects(request):
    search_query = ''
    if request.GET.get('search_query'):
       search_query = request.GET.get('search_query')

    tag = Tag.objects.filter(name__icontains=search_query)
    obj = Project.objects.distinct().filter(
    Q(title__icontains=search_query) |
    Q(describe__icontains=search_query) |
    Q(owner__name__icontains=search_query) |
    Q(tag__in=tag)
    )
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    results = 3
    paginator = Paginator(obj, results)
    try:
        obj = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        page = 1
        obj = paginator.page(page)
    except EmptyPage:
        page = paginator.num_pages
        obj = paginator.page(page)

    return render(request, 'projects/projects.html',{'list': obj})
```

Projects.html

```
 <div class="pagination">
      <ul class="container">
        <li><a href="#" class="btn btn--disabled">&#10094; Prev</a></li>
        {% for page in paginator.page_range %}
        <li><a href="?page={{page}}" class="btn btn--sub">{{ page }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
        <li><a href="#" class="btn">Next &#10095;</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Can you guys tell what could be the issue?

Comment: `Paginator(obj, results)` ...where does `obj` come from in this line?

Comment: @Anentropic I have added the previous code you can check

Comment: in your template you have `{% for page in paginator.page_range %}` but you are not passing any var named `paginator` into the render func... did you mean `{% for page in list.page_range %}`?